# Is there any specific method to handle big loops inside a useEffect in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I need to map through an array of users when the page reloads. Is there any way to optimize this? So that I don't have a performance issue in the future.

Comment: Does the result change often? If not, it could be stored and retrieved in `localStorage` or something like that?

Comment: The scenario is that when an admin needs to update a specific user I need to get the user id from the user's array that is in the redux store.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use an object instead of array, and store the user details by the user id like this:

```
{1: User, 2: User, 3: User}
```

and then you can just get the user by its id without having to loop through the array every time

Comment: Should I define a schema in mongo like that??